# How to inject class to project in order to avoid circular dependency

Tags: c#

Lets say I have two projects. Project A and Project B. 
In project A i have folder called "Components". In order to avoid circular dependency i moved this folder "Component" to new Project C. My problem is I can use Project C in Project A and Project B. But I need to use some classes from Project A in Project C, but then I can´t use project C reference in Project A, because of circular dependency. So how I can use these classes from Project A to Project C? And Also use Project C in Project A? Thanks!

Comment: Can't you move those classes to Project C as well?

Comment: @Streamline Sadly I can´t. They are the core classes of Project A. Its wpf application based on mvvm pattern.

Comment: Repeat the trick. Create a new assembly D to mediate between A and C. If you can't outright move classes, that may involve creating interfaces or wrapper types. Ultimately, all circular dependencies have to be broken by either adding new layer, or going the opposite way and fusing things together. (Technically, you can also use reflection to break the compile-time dependency and move it to runtime, but this has negative effects on readability, maintainability and performance.)

Comment: I assume MVVM project is a front end layer and other project is backend or business logic. If you have classes which are dependent on core types of MVVM then you need to think of redesign that structure.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Perhaps youre right. But we can´t simply redesign our project. We are working in industrial plant. And simply we can´t refactor yet because its time consuming, because we have more important tasks.

Comment: You can move the core classes of MVVM into another library D. And then use D into C and Use both D and C into A and use C into B. There is not short cut to solve your situation.

Comment: I suggest creating interface (or abstract class) in C, and let C depend on the interface not the concrete type. then you can implement the interface in A. Its also a good coding practice to decouple your stuff where possible.

Comment: @gerryc.inc You mean something like generic interface?

Comment: Depends on what exactly does project C needs from project A. Can be a simple interface of a generic one. Either way, the important part is that it decouples C from A. A will then implement the interface to provide the concrete implementations

Comment: @gerryc.inc Well actually in project C I need some classes and properties from project A. Then I will use that user control from project C in project A and project B.